# How to use the gRPC Python Plugin with Docker and Google Cloud Builds?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

**TL,DR;**

- What Linux Docker image would be fastest / lightest to run the Python gRPC plugin when generating API descriptor files?
- Should the aforementioned API descriptor become a Cloud Build [artifact](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts) and saved to a Cloud Storage Bucket?

  - ...in order to use `gcloud` to deploy the API to Cloud Endpoints.

**Detail**

I run a [Python gRPC service](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html) and ESP in Docker containers running on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/). [About gRPC > API management](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/about-grpc#api_management) shows a diagram of my application architecture:

[image]

My high-level build steps:

---

**1)** Create the **descriptor file**, `api_descriptor.pb`, using the protoc protocol buffers compiler.

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc \
    --include_imports \
    --include_source_info \
    --proto_path=. \
    --descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb \
    --python_out=generated_pb2 \
    --grpc_python_out=generated_pb2 \
    bookstore.proto
```

**2)** [Deploy the proto descriptor](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-grpc-compute-engine-docker#deploy_configuration) file (`api_descriptor.pb`) and the configuration file using the gcloud command-line tool:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy api_descriptor.pb api_config.yaml
```

**3)** [Generate gRPC code](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html#generate-grpc-code) using Python plugin:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../protos --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../protos/helloworld.proto
```

**4)** Build the final Docker image to deploy on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/). Resulting Docker image should include:

- Generated gRPC code from step 3).
- Any additional Python packages required by the gRPC server.

---

Step 4) builds the 'gRPC Server' (rightmost blue box in the accompanying diagram) using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python:latest

WORKDIR .
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "server.py"]

ADD requirements.txt .
ADD protos ./protos

RUN mkdir out

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python2.7 python-pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt


RUN python \
    -m grpc_tools.protoc \
    --python_out=out \
    --grpc_python_out=out \
    --proto_path=. \
    bookstore.proto
```

I'm migrating these build steps to Google's [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/).

AFAICT my high-level build steps should map onto Cloud Builder [official builder images](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders).

**1)** ???

2) Use [cloud-builders/gcloud/](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud) to run `gcloud` commands.

**3)** ???

4) Use [cloud-builders/docker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker) to build 'gRPC Server' Docker image.

Steps 2) and 3) already have cloud builders available (see [GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders)).

However, I'm unsure how to migrate steps **1)** and **3)** to Cloud Build. Both steps require running a Python plugin which is not available in a base Linux Docker image.

AFAICT step 1) should produce a Cloud Build [artifact](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts) for `api_descriptor.pb` and save to a Cloud Storage Bucket.

- What Linux Docker image would be fastest / lightest to run the Python gRPC plugin when generating API descriptor files?
- Should the aforementioned API descriptor become a Cloud Build [artifact](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts) and saved to a Cloud Storage Bucket?

  - ...in order to use `gcloud` to deploy the API to Cloud Endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working a few months ago. I don't know if I did it the "right" way. Judge for yourself :p

**TL,DR;** If you just want to use `protoc` with Google Cloud Build, I have submitted a `protoc` builder to the [cloud builders community GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/protoc) which has been accepted. See [cloud-builders-community/protoc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/protoc).

**Detail;** My solution relies on creating the `protoc` [Custom Build Step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps). This creates a Docker container image the Cloud Build worker pulls and runs when it needs to run `protoc`.

You only need two files to create the [Custom Build Step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps), `protoc`:

1. `cloudbuild.yaml` - tells Google Cloud Builder how to build a Docker image.
2. `Dockerfile` - tells Docker how to build the environment containing the `protoc` binary.

This was literally my local directory structure to achieve step 1:

```
.
├── cloudbuild.yaml
└── Dockerfile
```

The Docker file is where the `protoc` command is installed, and is the more complex of the two files:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG PROTOC_VERSION=3.6.1
ARG PROTOC_TARGET=linux-x86_64
ARG ASSET_NAME=protoc-${PROTOC_VERSION}-${PROTOC_TARGET}.zip

RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get -qy install python wget unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "${PROTOC_VERSION}/${ASSET_NAME}"

RUN wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v${PROTOC_VERSION}/protoc-${PROTOC_VERSION}-${PROTOC_TARGET}.zip && \
unzip ${ASSET_NAME} -d protoc && rm ${ASSET_NAME}

ENV PATH=$PATH:/protoc/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["protoc"]
CMD ["--help]
```

Breaking this down:

1. Define the first read only layer of the final "protoc" image we want to end-up with. I chose Ubuntu because it's the what I run locally. Any minimal Linux "base image" will do but it must have the following binaries installed: `apt-get`, `wget`, `unzip`, and `rm`:

`FROM ubuntu`

2. Set-up some variables that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the `--build-arg <varname>=<value>` flag:

`ARG PROTOC_VERSION=3.6.1`

`ARG PROTOC_TARGET=linux-x86_64`

`ARG ASSET_NAME=protoc-${PROTOC_VERSION}-${PROTOC_TARGET}.zip`

3. Run `apt-get -qy update` to "resynchronize the package index files from their sources". `q` omits progress indicators, `y` assumes yes as an answer to any prompts encountered:

`RUN apt-get -qy update`

4. Install **Python**, **Wget** (retrieves content from web server), and **Unzip**.

`RUN apt-get -qy install python wget unzip`

5. Remove any files created as part of the previous steps (and that are no longer needed):

`RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

The previous three [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) instructions can be combined into one:

`RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get -qy install python wget unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

6. Use the [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction to update the `PATH` environment to include the location of the `protoc` binary in the final environment (image).

`ENV PATH=$PATH:/protoc/bin/`

Set the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) of the image such that the image runs as a `protoc` executable. Not, since the previous step added `protoc` to `$PATH`, we need only specify the binary to run (not the full path):

`ENTRYPOINT ["protoc"]`

7. Use the [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) instruction so that if no options are provided when running the `protoc` image, `protoc --help` will run:

`CMD ["--help]`

That's all we need to define an executable `protoc` Docker image.  However, it's not yet a [Custom Build Step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps) that can be used in [Google's Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) environment. We must define the custom build step using `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '--tag',
        'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/protoc',
        '--cache-from',
        'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/protoc',
        '.',
      ]
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/protoc']
```

This file will generate an artefact `gcr.io/my-cloud-project-id/protoc` which can be used to run `protoc` in [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/). Example usage of this custom build step:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/protoc'
    args:
      [
        '--include_imports',
        '--include_source_info',
        '--proto_path',
        '.',
        '--descriptor_set_out',
        'api_descriptor.pb',
        'v1/my-api-proto.proto',
      ]
```

Cloud Build automatically replaces $PROJECT_ID with your project ID, so, the name will reference the artefact: `gcr.io/my-cloud-project-id/protoc`. Since this is an executable Docker image (defined with `ENTRYPOINT ["protoc"]`), it's equivalent to running locally:

`protoc --include_imports --include_source_info --proto_path . --descriptor_set_out api_descriptor.pb v1/my-api-proto.proto`

So, in answer to my question, both 1) and 3) can use the `protoc` custom build step to run in Google Cloud Build.